# Как передать cookie (токен аутентификации) в get- и post- запросах?

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Пытаюсь получить данные веб-сервиса. Провайдер веб-сервиса пишет -- "*Для начала вы посылаете запрос с Basic Auth к узлу passport.moex.com, указывая ваш логин и пароль (по сути это эквивалентно авторизации через браузер). В ответ вы получаете параметр MicexPassportCert, который следует сохранить на время работы с сервисом. Во всех остальных ваших запросах вы отдельно передаете в том числе этот параметр (так наша система понимает, от имени какой учетной записи запросы выполняются). Срок жизни MicexPassportCert составляет 24 часа с момента получения.*"

Токен MicexPassportCert получил следующим запросом. Код ниже.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

# указываем параметры аутентификации
url = 'https://passport.moex.com/authenticate'
auth = HTTPBasicAuth('ddd@mail.com', '112233')

session = requests.Session()
resp = session.get(url=url, auth=auth)

print(resp.status_code)
print(resp.text)
```

Теперь мне нужно отправить MicexPassportCert в запросе. Как это сделать?

Например, код ниже не работает. Получаю 200 с текстом "Пользователь не аутентифицирован!".

```
import requests

headers= {
    'Cookie': 'MicexPassportCert=**********************************',
        }

urlapi = 'https://otc-api-cabinet.moex.com/BrokerCode'

resp = requests.get(url=urlapi, headers=headers)
print(resp.text)
```

Где в запросе передавать MicexPassportCert, чтобы прошла моя аутентификация?

Comment: print(resp.text) можно увидеть? print(resp.cookies)?

Comment: В запросе к urlapi = 'https://otc-api-cabinet.moex.com/BrokerCode' -- print(resp.text) = "Пользователь не аутентифицирован!"

Comment: 'https://passport.moex.com/authenticate'

Comment: Там содержится значение MicexPassportCert -- 'hrv6TM2ZHUkvcxIH50QrwwEAAAANYOr14b7AcYANmcCqbttw3-rJFknRMvrakrBoN0Pi5EN_jKvV0ktO8L6YesQzaJE1vj7YXgpgzyjKS2JvbS5NPZVkD3RFO_AxxrZ2tM4Q5BmavyRAtNq-VQHYUiTH' (я только часть вам скопировал)

Comment: print(resp.text) = 'hrv6TM2ZHUkvcxIH50QrwwEAAAANYOr14b7AcYANmcCqbttw3...' (т.е. там закодированная строка токена)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140963/discussion-between---and-timovadia).

Answer (score 2):

Сам я с куками не работал, но судя по тому, что говорит мне гугл, передавать куки в запрос надо так:

```
resp = requests.get(url=urlapi, cookies=cookies)
```

Где в переменной coockies у вас лежит словарь, который вы можете достать из первого аутентификационного запроса так:

```
session = requests.Session()
resp = session.get(url=url, auth=auth)
cookies = resp.cookies  # Вот так вот
```

UPD: Попробуйте отправлять аутентификационный запрос и второй запрос в одной сессии. Так по идее куки должны автоматом подцепляться, если проблема с их передачей, то возможно это поможет:

```
session = requests.Session()
resp_auth = session.get(url=url, auth=auth)
# второй запрос в той же сессии, что и первый:
resp = session.get(url=urlapi)
```

Comment: Если прямо так, то этот вариант не работает. Получаю -- <Response [200]>
Пользователь не аутентифицирован!

Comment: Может первый запрос должен быть POST, чтобы авторизоваться, а второй (на другой URL)  GET?

Comment: Если в ответе на первый запрос есть MicexPassportCert - то, скорее всего, с запросом авторизации всё в порядке и надо разбираться, что не так со вторым запросом.

Comment: У них урлы разные. А что там ещё может быть не так?

Comment: Я добавил в мой ответ ещё один вариант, который можно попробовать